# Including boost in CMakeLists.txt (CLion)

Tags: c++, cmake, boost, boost-asio, clion

I am trying to include `boost` in my CLion project in CMakeLists.txt and I get an error in linking boost library.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(echo_ap)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)


set(Boost_Path "D:/boost_1_83_0/")
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR  "${Boost_Path}")
include_directories("D:/boost_1_83_0")
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS       ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED     ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME   OFF)


if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(Cyberforum ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()


add_executable(echo_ap main.cpp)
```

I want to include `boost/asio.hpp`.

I tried to solve this issue by adding this part of code:

```
target_link_libraries(echo_ap
        ws2_32
        wsock32
        )
```

But it didn't help. What's wrong here and what should I add in CMakeLists.txt to include boost?

Comment: You forgot to include into the question post the **error message** which you got.

Comment: You check for Boost_FOUND but where are you calling find_package or something like that?

Comment: Wait a minute there is no `find_package(Boost ...)` so `if(Boost_FOUND)` will not enter